# Prove that if $H$ is a subgroup of group $G$, $H\circ x=H$ if and only if $x\in H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that if $H$ is a subgroup of group $G$, $H\circ x=H$ if and only if $x\in H$.

Not sure how to start this proof about the right coset.

Comment: Avoid no-clue question: See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: If $H\cdot x=H$ there is a $y\in H$ such that $yx=1$

Comment: What have you tried? For $\implies$, just split into cases according to $x \in H, x \not \in H$. $\impliedby$ is even easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove this, you really just need to apply the definitions of a group and also you need to understand that a group is closed under its operation.

[image]

Comment: Bro wanted to flex his writing

Answer (score 0):

We can prove a general one:

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, $a,\,b\in G$. Then $aH=bH$ if and only if $a^{-1}b\in H$.

If $a^{-1}b\in H$, then $b=ah_0$ for some $h_0\in H$; thus $bh=a(h_0h)\in aH$ and $ah=b(h_0^{-1}h)\in bH$ for any $h\in H$, which means $aH=bH$.

If $aH=bH$, then $ah_1=bh_2$ for some $h_1,\,h_2\in H$, and so $a^{-1}b=h_1h_2^{-1}\in H$.

Answer (score 0):

Forward implication:

\begin{alignat}{1}
&H=Hx \Longrightarrow \\
&H\subseteq Hx \Longrightarrow \\
&\forall h \in H, \exists h'\in H \mid h=h'x \Longrightarrow \\
&\exists h'\in H \mid e=h'x \Longrightarrow \\
&H\ni h'=x^{-1}\Longrightarrow \\
&x\in H \\
\tag 1
\end{alignat}

Reverse implication:

\begin{alignat}{1}
&x\in H \Longrightarrow \\
&hx\in H, \forall h\in H\Longrightarrow \\
&Hx\subseteq H \\
\tag {2a}
\end{alignat}

and:

\begin{alignat}{1}
&x \in H \Longrightarrow \\
&\forall h \in H, h=(hx^{-1})x \in Hx \Longrightarrow \\
&H\subseteq Hx \\
\tag {2b}
\end{alignat}

By $(2a)$ and $(2b)$, $x\in H \Longrightarrow H=Hx$.