# Why does $xH=H$ imply that $x$ is element of $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It's not much, but I'm still a little bit confused about cosets, and I noticed that

> $xH = H$ implies $x$ to be an element of $H$.

Why does this make sense? Thank you!

Comment: Try thinking of $H$ as a set, such as $\{ e,h_1,h_2,...\}$.

Comment: $x\cdot e\in xH=H$

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3638184/750041

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $H$ is a subgroup, then the identity element $e\in H$, so $x=xe\in xH=H$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{alignat}{1}
&H=xH \Longrightarrow \\
&H\subseteq xH \Longrightarrow \\
&\forall h \in H, \exists h'\in H \mid h=xh' \Longrightarrow \\
&\forall h \in H, \exists h'\in H \mid x=hh'^{-1}\Longrightarrow \\
&x\in H
\end{alignat}